# Is it possible to use custom rotation for UIView when rotating device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am creating a camera-viewController for my application, and I'd like to use the same idea as used in the iOS default camera-app: the record-button is always on the same side of the device. Content is simply rotating with their own axis instead of the entire screen flipping around.

I have "successfully" created this. I am only allowing landscape. It looks something like this when opening it:

```
Figure 1

      <- top of device
------------------------------
| -------------------        |
||                   |       |
||                   |  ---  |
||    camera-view    | | ^ | |
||                   |  ---  |
||                   |       |
| -------------------        |
-----------------------------
```

When rotating the view to the other side, every element will rotate around themselves to show this (except for the camera):

```
Figure 2

       top of device ->
------------------------------
|        ------------------- |
|       |                   ||
|  ---  |                   ||
| | ^ | |    camera-view    || [top of device ->]
|  ---  |                   ||
|       |                   ||
|        ------------------- |
-----------------------------
```

The problem with this is that the entire view will rotate, so that the screen always will display `Figure 1` while "top of device" will change direction.

By returning `NO` in  `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate`, I get the result I want, though everything will be upside down, naturally.
Then, by registering for device-orientation-norifications, and using my own selector, I can programmatically rotate each control (e.g buttons, text, etc.) using e.g `[btnRecord setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI)];`

When setting the Transform to each control when rotating, while at the same time prevent the controller from actually rotating, I get the result I want. Kinda.

### The problem:

When using the method I've described above, I visually get the correct result, but I suspect I should manage this another way. When I receive notifications from other applications, such as Mail, Facebook, etc., they will always appear in the original orientation. Which makes sense. If this viewController starts in LandscapeLeft, and is then turned to LandscapeRight, all my controls and the entire view will animate and look perfect for that orientation, but incoming notifications will show upside down on the bottom of the screen. This is, of course, a result of me returning `NO` in `shouldAutorotate`.

In the default Camera-app, they have worked it out, so it must be possible.
Is there a way to enable autorotating, yet at the same time prevent the controller's view from actually rotating? The only solution I can think of at the time is to create an animation which perfectly counteracts the rotating animation, keeping it at bay, but this sounds awful, and I'd like to find a better way.

Comment: Do you hide the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the orientation in which your app was activated with use of the accelerometer:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {

    // [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates] doesn't stop
    // all gathered accelerometer data, but we want trigger it once.
    static BOOL read = NO;
    // applicationWillEnterForeground will happen lot of times :-)
    read = NO;

    CMMotionManager* motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];

    [motionManager
        startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:
            [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
        withHandler:
            ^(CMAccelerometerData* data, NSError* error) {
                if (!read) {
                    read = YES;
                    [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];

                    CGFloat accx = data.acceleration.x;
                    CGFloat accy = data.acceleration.y;

                    dispatch_async(
                        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                setStatusBarOrientation:
                                    deviceOrientationFromAcceleration(accx, accy)
                                animated:NO];
                        });
                    }
            }];
}
```

The `deviceOrientationFromAcceleration()` function is defined as

```
int deviceOrientationFromAcceleration(CGFloat x, CGFloat y) {
    // Get the current device angle
    float xx = -x;
    float yy = y;
    float angle = atan2(yy, xx);

    if (angle >= -2.25f && angle <= -0.75f) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
    else if (angle >= -0.75f && angle <= 0.75f) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    else if (angle >= 0.75f && angle <= 2.25f) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
    else if (angle <= -2.25f || angle >= 2.25f) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }

    return 0;
}
```